# How to animate an coordinate change of an MKPointAnnotation correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mkmapview

I want to animate an coordinate change of an MKPointAnnotation on a map view like this:

```
let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.873983, longitude: 12.627966)  

UIView.animate(withDuration: 20, animations: {
        self.myAnnotation.coordinate = destinationLocation
}, completion: nil)
```

I added the pin on the map like this:

```
let startPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.014542, longitude: 13.996593)

myAnnotation.coordinate = startPosition

mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)
```

myAnnotation is a global variable declared like this in my ViewController:

```
private let myAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
```

But when I zoom the map during the animation (method regionDidChangeAnimated from the MKMapViewDelegate is called) the position of the pin is moving to an wrong location on the map and not to the correct map coordinate during zooming.

I upload an Screencast here which describes the problem very well.

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/46a0ea2bdc0703ac392581532d3713f920170630095741/7f6499e7a38737a1f04740cd933ddaee20170630095741/dd2b2d

I don't know another possibility to provide a short video. The size is only 8 MB. That is the best way to see the issue.

Comment: Could you provide some more details meaning some more code of what you are doing?

Comment: Yes thanks Dido. I edit my question and I tried to provide more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever the user interacts with the map (zoom, scroll) you could/should stop the animation

```
if let annotationView = self.mapView.view(for: self.myAnnotation) {
    annotationView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

Furthermore you can implement the completion handler of your animation to act correctly on a canceled/successful animation:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 20, animations: {
    self.myAnnotation.coordinate = destinationLocation
}, completion:  { success in
    if success {
        // handle a successfully ended animation
    } else {
        // handle a canceled animation, i.e move to destination immediately
        self.myAnnotation.coordinate = destinationLocation
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the solution I was looking for :).

Comment: swift won't allow update coordinate at MKPointAnnotation

Comment: MKPointAnnotation.coordinate is declared { get set }:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpointannotation/1452620-coordinate but MKAnnotation has a readonly coordinate...